# Python3 / TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a python script on a Ubuntu PC. The purpose is to get monitoring information from the pc into a json-file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random, json, subprocess, psutil

json_key={}

def cpu_usage():
    cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2)
    json_key['cpu_usage'] = float(cpu_usage)

def cpu_temp():
    cpu_comm = "sensors |grep 'Core 0' |awk '{print $3}'|sed 's/\+//g;s/°C//g'"
    cpu_value = subprocess.check_output(cpu_comm, shell=True)
    json_key['cpu_temp'] = float(cpu_value.rstrip('\n'))

def disk_percent():
    cmd_uptime = "df -h |grep sda1| awk '{print $5}'| sed 's/%//g'"
    hdd_data = subprocess.check_output(cmd_uptime, shell=True)
    json_key['hdd_percent'] = float(hdd_data.rstrip('\n'))

def used_mem():
    mem_cmd = "free -m |egrep 'cache|Mem' |grep -v used|awk '{print $3}'"
    mem_used = psutil.virtual_memory()
    json_key['used_mem'] = mem_used.total >> 20

def percent_mem():
    mem_percent = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
    json_key['percent_mem'] = mem_percent

'''This function is used to retrive values used by td-agent'''
def print_json():
    print(json.dumps(json_key))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cpu_usage()
    cpu_temp()
    disk_percent()
    used_mem()
    percent_mem()
    print_json()
```

Unfortunately running the script gives me the following error:

```
uw@uw-SBC-FITPC2:~/Scripts$ sudo python3 usage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usage.py", line 36, in <module>
    cpu_temp()
  File "usage.py", line 15, in cpu_temp
    json_key['cpu_temp'] = float(cpu_value.rstrip('\n'))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

For the values:
cpu_comm equals "sensors |grep 'Core 0' |awk '{print $3}'|sed 's/+//g;s/°C//g'" and cpu_value equals "b'44.0\n'"

Is there any help to this?

Comment: Can you output the result of `cpu_value.rstrip('\n').decode()` because it seems this is in the wrong format...

Comment: Why are you using `decode()` in the first place? As the error states, that function requires a bytes-like object as input, not a `str`. I bet if you just remove `.decode()` from that line your code will work.

Comment: The problem was that the value of cpu_value was `b'44.0\n'` and expected was `44.0`. using `"cpu_value = subprocess.check_output(cpu_comm, shell=True, encoding='utf-8')"` did the trick

Comment: `cpu_value` is a `byes` object, you you need to pass a `bytes` object to `.rstrip`